# How detect change selected row from datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms

I need the "Write" label to be erased when the user selects an item. If the user hasn't entered anything, it should go back.

[image: editing flow]

I decided to catch the change event, but nothing works.

```
int selected_row = 0;
private void dataGridView2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Index != selected_row) {
        selected_row = dataGridView2.CurrentRow.Index;
        MessageBox.Show("Changed.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? If you have written some code that doesn't work as you expect then you should post this code. If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your observation is correct: intercepting the SelectionChanged event won't work because everything important has already taken place. Here's one simple way that I think might work for you. The thing to understand is that you're not really editing the cell itself when you're editing. Your keystrokes are going into the `DataGrid.EditingControl` that is superimposed on top of the cell.

So, first I suggest handling the `dataGridView.EditingControlShowing` event by clearing its text (which has been copied into it from the actual cell).

```
dataGridView.EditingControlShowing += (sender, e) =>
{
    // Clear the editing control text.
    e.Control.Text = string.Empty;
};
```

[image: blank cell to edit]

Then handle the `dataGridView.CellValidating` event, examine the `e.FormattedValue` property and if it's blank, or if you don't like what you see there, cancel the edit. That 'should' put the text back to where it was before the edit.

```
dataGridView.CellValidating += (sender, e) =>
{
    if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
    {
        dataGridView.CancelEdit();
    }
};
```

[image: revert cell]

---

Here's the code I used to test this answer:

```
namespace dgv_with_revert_non_commit
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            dataGridView.DataSource = DataSource;

            dataGridView.CellValidating += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
                {
                    dataGridView.CancelEdit();
                }
            };
            dataGridView.EditingControlShowing += (sender, e) =>
            {
                // Clear the editing control text.
                e.Control.Text = string.Empty;
            };

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                DataSource.Add(new Record { Index = i });
            }
        }
        readonly BindingList<Record> DataSource = new BindingList<Record>();
    }
```

This example uses a bound data source with this `Record` class.

```
    class Record
    {
        public int Index { get; set; }
        public string BurstTime { get; set; } = "Write";
    }
}
```